# how to get the video file name from datalist control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am displaying the video in datalist, I want to get the physical path of that video, can any 1 say how to do this?

```
 string aaa =FileUpload1.PostedFile.ToString();
 string filename =FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
```

I want to open the file from d:drive, so I want to get the full path, I tried the above code, but it returns only the filename.

Comment: Are you trying to get the physical path on the clients machine? if so, it's not possible.

Comment: @Darren,am going to save the file in client machine only, so I want to get

Comment: Sorry. No idea what you're trying to do. If you want to get the full path on the client there is no way to do it. If you're trying to save on the server then it's fileupload1.SaveAs(filenameandpathonserver)